# SmtpException from WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: smtpclient, socketexception, system.net.webexception

I am trying to send mail using smtp server but i am getting following Exception.
Please give me some advice..

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
>   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 184.xx.xxx.xx:25
>    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
>    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket 6, Int32 timeout)
>    at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>    at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
>    at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncD elegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at testEmail.Module1.Main() in E:\testEmail\testEmail\Module1.vb:line 17

Answer (score 0):

The message tells me that your webserver has problems connectiong to your SMTP server. Are you sure the SMTP address is right?

Remember that some SMTP-servers need logon

Also some SMTP servers will not let you connect if your use a different IPS

I would change the SMTP to the one your ISP has.
You can try to connect to the SMTP with Telnet to check your connection

```
telnet YourSmtpAddress 25
```

Comment: Can you ping it, or telnet to it on port 25?

Comment: i am not able to connect to my SMTP Server using telnet with port 25.Is ISP block my port 25?

Comment: What is the massage you get: Does it just say Trying... or do you get an error-message?

Comment: Remember that the SMTP server you need to use is the one that your client uses. So if the client has a different ISP then you, you need to use a different SMTP server. That is if you do not have your own SMTP server.

Comment: It shows following message                                          Microsoft Telnet> open mail.xxxxx.com 25
Connecting To mail.xxxxx.com...Could not open connection to the host, on
 port 25: Connect failed

Comment: Problem resolved.
I used Port 587 instead of 25.
You can also check with Port 465.

Answer (score 0):

From this messagge

**A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 184.xx.xxx.xx:25**

it seems that you cannot reach the SMTP address.

Check your internet connection and then check if the address is correct.
A Ping to the address or a tracerout can help you understand why you cannot contact the server, if the address is correct